# Call a IEnumerator method from another script in Unity and get its return value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity. I have this file:

**API.cs** (no attached to any GameObject)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;

public class API : MonoBehaviour
{

    public IEnumerator Login(string email, string psw)
    {
        string URL = "https://####.azurewebsites.net/api/login";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("email", email);
        form.AddField("password", psw);

        var download = UnityWebRequest.Post(URL, form);

        // Wait until the download is done
        yield return download.SendWebRequest();

        if (download.isNetworkError || download.isHttpError)
        {
            print("Error downloading: " + download.error);
        }
        else
        {
            JsonData data = JsonMapper.ToObject(download.downloadHandler.text);
            string token = (string)data["success"]["token"];
            Debug.Log(token);
        }
    }
}
```

**caller.cs** (attached to a GameObject in the current scene)

```
    private void Start ()
    {
        // Something like this
        var token = API.Login("foo@boo.com", "####");
    }
```

My question is: **How can I call the function "Login" in caller.cs and retrieve the value of the token?**

---

**What I have tried and didn't work:**

- Create a variable for the script `public API test;` and then `test.Login("foo@boo.com", "####")`
- Make the API class static, inizialize the class in caller.cs, and then call the method Login(...)

---

**EDIT 1:**

Was able to solve the problem of calling the method from another script, the problem was that I had to create an object and attach to it API.cs. Then I also had to drag and drop that object in the public field of caller.cs in the inspector. Moreover, I had to add in caller.cs the Login method inside the StartCoroutine() one.

Still, have to figure out now **how to retrieve the value of the token from the Login() method.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was able to solve the problem of calling the method from another
>   script, the problem was that I had to create an object and attach to
>   it API.cs. Then I also had to drag and drop that object in the public
>   field of caller.cs in the inspector.

That doesn't sound right dragging and dropping the script manually in the Editor since your goal is to do with from script. The `API` script is a `MonoBehaviour` because it derives from it. Use `AddComponent` to add the `API` class then call `StartCoroutine` on the Login function.

```
API api = gameObject.AddComponent<API>();
StartCoroutine(api.Login("foo@boo.com", "####"));
```

Remove the `MonoBehaviour` so that you don't have to attach the API script to a GameObject instead create `new` objects with the new keyword.

```
public class API 
{

    public IEnumerator Login(string email, string psw)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Noe, you can simply do:

```
API api = new API();
StartCoroutine(api.Login("foo@boo.com", "####"));
```

Finally, to return the value, add `Action` as third param.

```
public class API
{

    public IEnumerator Login(string email, string psw, Action<string> token)
    {
        string URL = "https://####.azurewebsites.net/api/login";
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("email", email);
        form.AddField("password", psw);

        var download = UnityWebRequest.Post(URL, form);

        // Wait until the download is done
        yield return download.SendWebRequest();

        if (download.isNetworkError || download.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error downloading: " + download.error);
        }
        else
        {
            JsonData data = JsonMapper.ToObject(download.downloadHandler.text);
            string tokenResult = (string)data["success"]["token"];
            Debug.Log(tokenResult);
            if (token != null)
                token(tokenResult);
        }
    }
}
```

To call it from your non coroutine function:

```
API api = new API();
StartCoroutine(api.Login("foo@boo.com", "####", (token) =>
{
    Debug.Log("Token: " + token);
}
));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and what a really clean way to solve this. Thank you so much @Programmer. Anyways, just one little thing: there is a little error here `string token = (string)data["success"]["token"];` because the variable token was already used. Simply rename it there and everywhere it appears. Thank you again, man, cheers!

Comment: Yup. Didn't notice the variable used problem but glad you fixed it. I also edited the answer to fix that. You're welcome!